# Maximum Density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

I was wondering about what triggers black hole formation, e.g. in the core of a neutron star that gets too massive.  Does the matter there have to exceed some density threshold so that the space time curvature reaches a threshold value and a chain reaction collapse starts?

I tried to take the Schwartzchild radius formula and plug in (density)*(volume of a sphere), to solve for a density value, but all that produced was

Density = (Some Constant)/r^2

And I'm not sure if that means anything.

So I suppose this is two different but related questions:

1. By what specific process is black hole formation "triggered" in a body that is too small but gathers more mass, and
2. Is there a maximum density for matter, and if so what is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neutron stars become black holes at masses comparable to the [Tolman Oppenheimer Volkoff limit.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit)

The conceptual explanation of the TOV [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation) is that the pressure necessary to hold up the star against gravitational collapse is a form of energy=mass, which in turn gravitates.

When the pressure becomes comparable to the rest mass, two things happen. The pressure is now significantly contributing to the gravitational force which is acting to collapse the neutron star, whereas in normal stars the pressure mostly acts to counteract the gravitational force. Furthermore, the degeneracy pressure changes from $P \sim \rho^{5/3}$ to $P \sim \rho^{4/3}$ as it becomes [relativistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas#Relativistic_Fermi_gas). Relativistic degeneracy pressure alone has a mass limit, the TOV limit. After adding the effect of strong nuclear forces, neutron stars have a mass limit slightly higher than the TOV limit.

1. Black hole formation is triggered whenever the TOV equation cannot be solved--whenever pressure cannot counteract gravity.
2. Higher density matter is higher energy matter because short length scales correspond with high energy scales. Unfortunately, we don't know enough about high energy scales to say what the maximum possible density is.

For an object of given density $\rho$, with approximate mass $\rho R^{3}$, compare $c^{2} < \frac{GM}{R} = \frac{G\rho R^{3}}{R} = G\rho R^{2}$. It's clear that density alone does not define a black hole--the overdensity must be large enough in length.